# fitting curve to my data and calculating fwhm

Tags: r, fitting, gaussian-mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

Hello and thank you in advance for your inputs. I am trying to find a model in R that will give me curves that fit my data. I am aiming for 2 peaks (i am thinking of normal distributions but might be wrong) I am trying to extrapolate from the fit information on the full width half maximum of each of the two peaks(at 14,21) and their peak values as well as the distance between the middle point of the two peaks and the x-axis. Below is my data that are obtained from image profiles.

```
xval<- seq(1,32,1)
yval<- c(0, 69, 38, 13, 30, 86, 121, 160, 201, 169, 208, 144, 500, 756, 705, 487, 417, 455, 564, 737, 1027, 748, 212, 46, 36, 54, 121, 209, 124, 104, 117, 112)
```

And the plot in R
[image]

Comment: This is a standard task in chromatography, although your resolution is very low. Package [xcms](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/xcms.html) looks promising, but I haven't tested it (since my GC software does peak detection for me).

Comment: I could get a fairly good fit to a double Lorentzian peak equation using some of my Python peak fitting code, so if you can't find anything else reply here as a last resort and I'll post the code.

Comment: My supervisor decided to go another direction and i am using departmental dedicated software calculating the values i need by interpolation. I appreciate your inputs.